# mysql connector problems

Tags: mysql, odbc

I have problems with MySQL Connector (MyConnector)

it seem there is a problem when I modify my connection via ODBC, I can create new entries, but I am unable to edit them..

I found a patch for windows 7, 32Bit. but I also need a fix for Windows 7, 64bit.

Comment: Yeah. Have you got your user rights right? What patch are you talking about here? What doesn't work? What error messages do you get?

Comment: why are you using ODBC ?

Comment: I use ODBC for easy connectivity, however many people have recently suggested to use anydac or similar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the connector for Windows 7 is 64-bit is the same as the one for 32-bit(x86)

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/5.1.html

Would the patch be different for the two CPU types?

Comment: when I applied the dll patch manually, I could not open new ODBC connection unfortunately :(